# Interpolation function approx() in r gives error - need at least two non-NA values to interpolate

Tags: r, line, gis, interpolation

I am using R Studio on Windows 8 machine. I am trying to interpolate a point between two points.

```
x1 = -159.9, y1 = 56.5, 
x2 = -159.9, y2 = 56.3
```

I am using `approx()` function in the following manner (reproducible)

```
approx(c(-159.9,-159.9), c(56.5,56.3), n = 3)
```

which gives me an error

```
Error in approx(c(-159.9, -159.9), c(56.5, 56.3), n = 3) : 
need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
```

Its expecting two non-NA values, which I have provided.

The function is working flawlessly for other points. Just this is the problem. 
If you have come across any such error, please let me know how did you solve this?

Comment: You have the x and y coordinates in the wrong order. The `approx` function can't interpolate values where the x-coordinates are the same, however, this is exactly what you do at the moment.

Comment: Your both `x1` and `x2` is the same value

Comment: @robbertjan94 that seems the cause of error. What should I do to handle it, becasue I just can't simply change the order, because at times y1 and y2 will also be the same.

Comment: So here's how I am tackling the issue. I interchange x with y whenever the x1 and x2 are the same, and later interchange the order of the columns.

Answer (score 3):

From the **Details** of `?approx()`:

> The inputs can contain missing values which are deleted, so at least
>   two complete (x, y) pairs are required (for method = "linear", one
>   otherwise). If there are duplicated (tied) x values and ties is a
>   function it is applied to the y values for each distinct x value.

Comment: So what should I do when x1 and x2 are the same as I need to interpolate y values in this case?

Comment: continuing reading the same page: `Useful functions in this context include mean, min, and max. If ties = "ordered" the x values are assumed to be already ordered. The first y value will be used for interpolation to the left and the last one for interpolation to the right.`

Answer (score 3):

The `approx` function can't interpolate values where the x-coordinates are the same.

Hence, I would tackle this problem as follows:

1. Group all the cases where the x-coordinates are equal and aggregate them by for example the median, mean, or a custom built function
2. Use you intended interpolation scheme, for example the `approx` function.